# Combining Multiple Datasets Based on Common Values: A Code for Data Integration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a problem with a lot of slowness and inefficiency when I work with large databases, so I decided to publish it to receive assistance to solve the problem and achieve the same result. I want to keep my database updated as new combinations are found. I will explain below!

CSV's example:

`aaa_database.csv`

```
pressure_id,pressure_name,betfair_id,betfair_name,xg_id,xg_name
168090,Abha,12345,Abha Cadabra,150414,Abha
354394,FK Mladost GAT,40492492,FK Mladost Novi Sad,1266892,FK Mladost Novi Sad
```

`aaa_pressure.csv`

```
match_id,home_id,home_name,away_id,away_name
11220805,5144,FK Javor Ivanjica,354394,FK Mladost GAT
10913396,168090,Abha,229347,Al-Adalah
10913385,56031,Al-Raed,168084,Al-Batin
```

`aaa_betfair.csv`

```
match_id,home_id,home_name,away_id,away_name
32309475,204683,Cottbus,7458145,BFC Dynamo
32310931,13504616,FK Javor Ivanjica,40492492,FK Mladost Novi Sad
32318823,20860826,FC Pucioasa,17687110,FCSB II
11111111,12345,Abha Cadabra,6789,Al Adala
```

`aaa_xg.csv`

```
match_id,home_id,home_name,away_id,away_name
3967968,2211,Shirak,6345,Pyunik
3978692,4617,FK Neftchi,7981,Qarabag FK
3900303,187880,Botev Vratsa,10128,PFC Lokomotiv Sofia 1929
4063780,150414,Abha,582816,Al-Adalah
4063790,150413,Al-Raed,582752,Al Batin
4159060,2391,Javor,1266892,FK Mladost Novi Sad
```

I have access to three databases that provide the `match_id`, `home_id`, `home_name`, `away_id`, and `away_name`.

If a record of a team already exists in my `aaa_database.csv` and its `id` is found in all three in `home_id`, then it should create a new row in my database with the data of the away team (`away_id` and `away_name`).

If all three `id` are found in `away_id`, then it should create a new row in my database with the data of the home team (`home_id` and `home_name`).

If it already exists in the database, then there is no need to add it again.

```python
import pandas as pd

database = pd.read_csv('aaa_database.csv', dtype=str)
pressure = pd.read_csv('aaa_pressure.csv', dtype=str)
betfair = pd.read_csv('aaa_betfair.csv', dtype=str)
xgoals = pd.read_csv('aaa_xg.csv', dtype=str)

merged_pressure_home = pd.merge(database, pressure[['home_id', 'away_id', 'away_name']], left_on='pressure_id', right_on='home_id')
merged_betfair_home = pd.merge(database, betfair[['home_id', 'away_id', 'away_name']], left_on='betfair_id', right_on='home_id')
merged_xgoals_home = pd.merge(database, xgoals[['home_id', 'away_id', 'away_name']], left_on='xg_id', right_on='home_id')

new_rows = [{'pressure_id': merged_pressure_home['away_id'].iloc[i],
             'pressure_name': merged_pressure_home['away_name'].iloc[i],
             'betfair_id': merged_betfair_home['away_id'].iloc[i],
             'betfair_name': merged_betfair_home['away_name'].iloc[i],
             'xg_id': merged_xgoals_home['away_id'].iloc[i],
             'xg_name': merged_xgoals_home['away_name'].iloc[i]}
            for i in range(len(merged_betfair_home))]

merged_pressure_away = pd.merge(database, pressure[['away_id', 'home_id', 'home_name']], left_on='pressure_id', right_on='away_id')
merged_betfair_away = pd.merge(database, betfair[['away_id', 'home_id', 'home_name']], left_on='betfair_id', right_on='away_id')
merged_xgoals_away = pd.merge(database, xgoals[['away_id', 'home_id', 'home_name']], left_on='xg_id', right_on='away_id')

new_rows += [{'pressure_id': merged_pressure_away['home_id'].iloc[i],
              'pressure_name': merged_pressure_away['home_name'].iloc[i],
              'betfair_id': merged_betfair_away['home_id'].iloc[i],
              'betfair_name': merged_betfair_away['home_name'].iloc[i],
              'xg_id': merged_xgoals_away['home_id'].iloc[i],
              'xg_name': merged_xgoals_away['home_name'].iloc[i]}
             for i in range(len(merged_betfair_away))]

new_teams = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
new_teams = new_teams.merge(database, how="left", indicator=True)
new_teams = new_teams[new_teams["_merge"] == "left_only"]
new_teams = new_teams[database.columns]

database = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(new_teams), database], ignore_index=True)
database.to_csv('aaa_database.csv', index=False)
```

`aaa_database.csv` after run my code:

```
pressure_id,pressure_name,betfair_id,betfair_name,xg_id,xg_name
229347,Al-Adalah,6789,Al Adala,582816,Al-Adalah
5144,FK Javor Ivanjica,13504616,FK Javor Ivanjica,2391,Javor
168090,Abha,12345,Abha Cadabra,150414,Abha
354394,FK Mladost GAT,40492492,FK Mladost Novi Sad,1266892,FK Mladost Novi Sad
```